# One command for multiple deployments

Tags: android, ios, deployment, react-native, command-line-interface

I'd like to know if some of you worked out how to generate signed APKs and IPA with multiple configurations (ie : beta for hockeyapp, and production for stores) in a single command.

I'm exploring all the possibilities there, it looks like there are lots of ways to do this.

I'd also like to be able to pass a variable like ENVIRONMENT to set Javascript constants such as an API url or turn on/off debugs.
Here's what I'm thinking right now :

Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config to solve the former problem.

On android :

I'm thinking about adding a type in buildTypes in gradle. So far, I couldn't get it to work, I'm not very experienced with native configurations.

I would then make a bash script to create the offline bundle with the chosen env (staging / dev / prod) and use gradle's assembleRelease / assembleBeta. Do you think that's doable ?

On iOS, it looks a bit more complicated :

It looks like it's hard to change the project's configuration in CLI when building. So I was thinking that I should duplicate the project for each environement : project-dev.xcodeproj, project-prod.xcodeproj... you got the point.

Once again, I would make the bundle, then cp it inside the given project. A nice touch would be to trigger the xcode compilation in CLI too, I don't know if this is hard to set up.

What do you think about this ? Maybe some of you are already using custom scripts to do that ?

The icing on the cake would be to use HockeyApp's 'puck' cli tool to upload it, but that should be quite easy to set up once the application has been build for both iOS and Android.

Comment: I have no understanding of HockeyApp, but I use a script to build my .IPA files for release, then resign them for internal testing so that I can test EXACTLY what I am submitting to the customer or the app store.  It's a bit of a long process, but let me know if you would like to see the steps involved.

Comment: Sure, I'd really like to know :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the process I use for command line build with parameters.  My system builds a release version .ips file and then copies and resigns that file with a development provisioning profile that I can put on my development devices to test exactly what is being sent to the customer or to the app store.  Not all of this will be useful to you, but hopefully some will.

First, I have a variables file that sets the global parameters that I'm going to use for the build:

```
Scheme="(The scheme I am going to build inside my project)"
WindowsSavePath="(path to my source archive directory on a shared computer)"
InstallSavePath="(path to my .ipa archive directory on a shared computer"
Customer="(relative path inside archive directories)"
Fleet="(Continued relative path)"
PathToProject="(path to the folder on my Mac with the xcode project file)"
ProjectName="(project name).xcodeproj"
PlistPath="$Scheme-Info.plist"
appScheme="$Scheme"
AppName="(The name that I want to give my .ipa file)"
Version="(The version number for this build)"
AppendedFileName="-QA" //I use this for QA and Production distinction
exportPath="$InstallSavePath/$Fleet/$Customer/$Version$AppendedFileName/"
CompanyAppIdentifierPrefix="(my generic provisioning profile identifier)"
ArchiveLocation="$WindowsSavePath/$Fleet/$Customer/$Version$AppendedFileName"
SourceCodeDestination="(my compiled absolute path to the archive directories)"
```

This is all contained in a SetVariables.sh file.  Now we get to start building the project.  In another .sh file first I call the SetVariables file, then I start compilation:

```
 #Update the version number in the plist file for the project
/usr/libexec/PListBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $Version" "$PathToProject/$PlistPath"
/usr/libexec/PListBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $BuildVersion" "$PathToProject/$PlistPath"

#Now build and archive the project, the create the .ipa file for either submittal or giving to customers
mkdir -p "$exportPath"
mkdir -p "${ArchiveLocation}/dSYM"
xcodebuild  -project "$PathToProject/$ProjectName" -scheme "$Scheme" DSTROOT="$exportPath" DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT="dwarf-with-dsym" DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH="${ArchiveLocation}/dSYM" archive -archivePath "$exportPath${appScheme} $Version$AppendedFileName.xcarchive"
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${exportPath}Applications/${AppName}.app" -o "${exportPath}${appScheme} $Version$AppendedFileName.ipa"

#Now resign and create an internal dev version to test on development ipads
rm -r Payload SwiftSupport
unzip -q "${exportPath}${appScheme} $Version$AppendedFileName.ipa"

BUNDLE_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" "Payload/${AppName}.app/Info.plist")
. ./CreateInternalEntitlements.sh "$CompanyAppIdentifierPrefix.$BUNDLE_ID"
. ./resign.sh "${exportPath}${appScheme} $Version$AppendedFileName.ipa" "${exportPath}${appScheme} ${Version}${AppendedFileName} Internal" internalDev.mobileprovision "(My developer account tied to the internal provisioning profile" Entitlements.plist
rm -r Payload SwiftSupport

#Now delete the intermediate files from the installs directory
rm -rf "$exportPath${appScheme} $Version$AppendedFileName.xcarchive"
rm -rf "${exportPath}Applications"
```

I have left out a few things in there (resign.sh, createentitlements.sh), but those processes I found on stackoverflow, so it shouldn't be too hard for you to find as well.

I've never done it, but I'm relatively certain that you can change the command line arguments for the `xcodebuild` to build either release or debug like you are trying to do.  You could also run the `xcodebuild` twice, once for debug and once for release, and save the builds to different locations.

I hope this helps you at least a little with your goals.  This took my a week or two to put all together and get working for my needs.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Plistbuddy, I'll look into your example.